# Select children based on nth,mth,oth,..., pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a div with many div children, and a runtime derived number `ChildrenPerRow`, how can I select all of the children in each 'virtual' row that is not the last element on that virtual row?

For example, if `ChildrenPerRow = 5`, The selector should return the 1st,2nd,3rd,4th, 6th,7th,8th,9th,11th,12th,13th,14th, etc. If `ChildrenPerRow = 4`, the selector should return the 1st,2nd,3rd,5th,6th,7th,9th,10th,11th,13th,14th,15th etc.

I've tried using something like:

```
var FilterStr = '';
for(var i=1; i<ChildrenPerRow;i++){
   FilterStr+=':nth-child('+i+'n),';
}
FilterStr = FilterStr.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
$Children.filter(FilterStr).doSomething();
```

Which produces a selector like:

```
:nth-child(1n),:nth-child(2n),:nth-child(3n),:nth-child(4n)
```

But this selects every child. I also feel like using a look to build a selector string is inefficient. I'm thinking this could be done using a not selector, but I'd like to know how to do it with a positive selector too.

So the question is, what's an efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$Children.filter(':not(:nth-child(' + ChildrenPerRow + 'n))');
```

Without the `:not()` selector you'd have to build a selector like this:

```
$Children.filter(':nth-child(5n+1), :nth-child(5n+2), :nth-child(5n+3), :nth-child(5n+4)')
```

Comment: I think this is it, let me check when I get back.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly

```
 $("div div").not(":last-child");
```

should be enough,

for the 10 child divs

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
</div>
```

it will return 8, ommiting the last child of every parent div

A DEMO fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/1yg3z86p/1/

Comment: The rows are not wrapped in divs, they are 'virtual' rows, so its one container div with many immediate children divs. The items per row changes based on the parent container's width.

Comment: OK, in that case, vote up for Dave, charlietfl would work as well, though it should be !== ChildrenPerRow - 1 to exclude the last element

Answer (score 1):

Can use the `index` argument of `filter(fn)` to make something more readable

```
$('.parentClass .childClass').filter(function(index){
   return index % (ChildrenPerRow-1) !==0;
}).doSomething();
```